# Content Security Policy Configuration Problems

Tags: nginx, security, configuration

I have a server running nginx and I would like to add CSP. However I'm encountering difficulties even after following numerous guides I will either get an error from nginx or they just don't work. Here is what the header looks like at the moment:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; \
script-src 'self' google-analytics.com; \
img-src 'self' google-analytics.com;
```

Using this entry however causes nginx to report that there's an error in the config file. I want to restrict access to both myself and Google Analytics as it's the only thing I'm not serving from nginx.

[Nginx Configuration file](http://pastebin.com/YgwYy3WA)

Comment: And what was the error that it reported?

Comment: @MichaelHampton
"Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unexpected "c" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www:80
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"

Comment: You should look at that line, then.

Comment: I have and normally the only way I can find to correct it to try a completely different configuration which once again gets an error or just doesn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what's on line 80 of that file, since you didn't post it for us to look at. There's no way anyone can help you under those circumstances.

Comment: Line 80 is a comment
#       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

Comment: Just stop wasting time and post the whole thing.

Comment: I've put the config file on Pastebin, I've also updated the original question but here is the link:
http://pastebin.com/YgwYy3WA

Comment: Certainly based on the code you pasted here, you're missing a closing " mark on the last line.  I imagine 4.5 years on this information is of little use to you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the closing quotation mark (") and semicolon (;) on line 40.

Nginx shows the error on line 80 because it is the next occurrence of a quote in the file.